# TYPO3 calling an action

Tags: controller, typo3, call, action

I have a question relating to TYPO3. Does anybody here have experience with it?

I have a module named locations.
A controller named `LocationController`
A function called `generateCountryAction()`
this function returns a list of all countries which I input in JSON format.

For now, on home page, I need to build a map and display all country on that map.
So, I need to call this function to get list of countries then pass the result to javascript. Because I used a javascript library to build the map.

But I don't know how to call this function. Which url will be used?
So, can you help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could follow this example and then come back with any questions you might have:
https://usetypo3.com/json-view.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax calling this function. You need to use onclick event to get all list of countries in frontend. Use ajax in typo3 like below.

call `EidDispatcher.php` in  `ext_localconf.php` file and add this fiel on this path `Classes/Ajax/` like below.

`$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['eID_include']['your_ajax_parameters'] = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('extension_key').'Classes/Ajax/EidDispatcher.php'`;

You can call controllers methos like this.

```
$.ajax({
    async: 'true',
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        eID: "your_ajax_parameters",
        id:pageId,
        tx_extension_key: {
            pluginName:  'your plugin name',
            controller:  'your controller name',
            action:      'your action name',
        },
        param:{
            parameter:'',
        }
    },
    success:function (data) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But when I do like above, it always return null

In controller I have this
public function testAction() {
     echo json_encode(array('come here'));
     die();
    }

In ext_localconf.php I have this 
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Locations.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'MapGeneration',
    array(
        'Location' => 'test, list',
    )
);

Do you know why the result is empty?

Comment: You can get parameters value in controller like this. **$paramArr = GeneralUtility::_GET('param');**

Comment: Hi,
But I think that, it still cannot call the action.
The link called is 
index.php?eID=mapGeneration&id=237&tx_extension_key%5BextensionName%5D=Locations&tx_extension_key%5BpluginName%5D=MapGeneration&tx_extension_key%5Bcontroller%5D=Location&tx_extension_key%5Baction%5D=test&param%5Bparameter%5D=
But value return is blank.

Comment: **tx_extension_key** here replace your extension key. this only for example

Comment: Thanks. I cannot found any similar result as I want.
I tried 
success:function (data) {
console.log(data)
    }
But it seem that this code is not was called.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach: https://github.com/helhum/typoscript_rendering

It just provides viewhelpers wich you can use to generate links to controllers and actions without the overhead of eId or special page-types. It just works.